# Create document arrays with least and highest count on a grouping key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have below collection

```
[
  {
    _id: {
      giftId: "coin",
      userId: "5b839dfeaaafc94ff323da35"
    },
    count: 1
  },
  {
    _id: {
      giftId: "coin",
      userId: "5b8390cc4bf35e13fe67d545"
    },
    count: 2
  },
  {
    _id: {
      giftId: "Gold",
      userId: "5b8390cc4bf35e13fe67d545"
    },
    count: 3
  },
  {
    _id: {
      giftId: "Gold",
      userId: "5b8390cc4be35e13fe67d545"
    },
    count: 1
  },
  {
    _id: {
      giftId: "Silver",
      userId: "5b8390cc4bf35e13fe67d545"
    },
    count: 4
  },
  {
    _id: {
      giftId: "Silver",
      userId: "5b8390cc4bf35e13ff67d545"
    },
    count: 2
  }
]
```

I need below output

```
[{
    array1: [{
    _id: {
      giftId: "coin",
      userId: "5b8390cc4bf35e13fe67d545"
    },
    count: 2
  },
  {
    _id: {
      giftId: "Gold",
      userId: "5b8390cc4bf35e13fe67d545"
    },
    count: 3
  },
  {
    _id: {
      giftId: "Silver",
      userId: "5b8390cc4bf35e13fe67d545"
    },
    count: 4
  }],
    array2: [{
      _id: {
        giftId: "coin",
        userId: "5b839dfeaaafc94ff323da35"
      },
      count: 1
  }, {
    _id: {
      giftId: "Silver",
      userId: "5b8390cc4bf35e13ff67d545"
    },
    count: 2
      },{
    _id: {
      giftId: "Gold",
      userId: "5b8390cc4be35e13fe67d545"
    },
    count: 1
  }]
}]
```

I need count for each `giftId` in an array of objects.
Suppose in above document for `giftId` **coin** we have 2 count and for `giftId` **Gold** we have 3 count
and for `giftId` **Silver** we have 4 count. So all the values with hight count should be in same array.

Any help would be highly appriciated!!!

I am using latest version of mongodb **4.0**

Comment: Downvoter please explain the reason .

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more how you would like to group? What should go into which array and why?

Comment: @dnickless Thank you for the reply. Actually I need separate array  for each `giftId` **(coin, silver, gold)** having higher counts. Please have a look at above output. **array1** has all the `giftId` with the higher counts and similarly for the **array2**.

Comment: So every array should have the same giftIds in it so an equal number can be assumed? 2*gold, 2*silver, 2*coin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation query.

`$sort` to sort the data by count.

Initial `$group` to get the max and min doc element for each gift_id followed by `$group` to push the max and min value documents into array.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$sort":{"count":-1}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.giftId","maxdoc":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}, "mindoc":{"$last":"$$ROOT"}}},
  {"$group":{"_id":null,"array1":{"$push":{"_id":"$maxdoc._id", "count":"$maxdoc.count"}}, "array2":{"$push":{"_id":"$mindoc._id", "count":"$mindoc.count"}}}},
  {"$project":{"_id":0}}
])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, please check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/LoUQeTdBTte
Second array is right but first is wrong. please help me for this ....

Comment: Yw. What should be in the first array ? How is it different from second array ?

Comment: First three arrays should be combined as the having least counts with each `giftId`. Last array is correct with different `giftId` and highest counts.

Comment: Updated. Can you pls give it a try one more time ?